# In which finite groups is there a non-central g such that, for all irreducible characters, Chi(i)(g) <> zero?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, characters

What is the character of Pi(G), the tensor product of all inequivalent irreducible representations of G?

Comment: Dear @john mckay, the question in the title appears to differ from the question in the body of the post.

Comment: The ax+b group of a finite field ought to work (it has trivial centre). Did you have other examples in mind?

Comment: @RicardoAndrade True, but the question in the title is equivalent to asking "in which finite groups is there a non-central $g$ such that $\pi(g)\neq 0$"

Answer (score 6):

I'm refering to the question in the title. Elements such that $\chi(g)\neq 0$ for all $\chi\in \operatorname{Irr}G$ are called nonvanishing elements in the literature. They were studied by Isaacs, Navarro and Wolf (Group elements were no irreducible character vanishes, J. Algebra 222 (1999), 413-423, [MR1733678](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1733678), [Doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1999.8007)) and others (search for papers that cite the paper just mentioned). Isaacs, Navarro and Wolf prove (among other things) that in a nilpotent group, all nonvanishing elements are central. On the other hand, Miyamoto (J. Algebra 364 (2012), 88-89, [MR2927049](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2927049), [doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2012.04.018)) showed that any nontrivial solvable group has nonvanishing elements different from $1$. Thus at least every solvable groups with trivial center is a group as in the question title. A paper of Dolfi et. al. (J. Algebra 323 (2010), 540-545, [MR2564856](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2564856), [doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2009.08.014)) contains a number of nonsolvable examples.